# Cancel RecyclerView vertical fling/swipe

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I am currently detecting when a specific view becomes visible to the user or goes out of sight and stopping the `RecyclerView` scroll at that view position. So far I have been able to achieve this with the help of the `OnScrollListener` together with `RecyclerView.stopScroll` and `RecyclerView.scrollTo`, but the only issue now is that if the user flings the list it will get past that view position since the fling is still "acting" after the scroll to position has been called, causing the list to overshoot the item position.

How can I end the user fling action programmatically? Something like `recyclerView.fling(0)` exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using `LinearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset` with the position of the target and 0 as the offset after calling `RecyclerView.stopScroll`.

So far the fling behavior is no longer causing the list scroll to overshoot the intended position when using these two together.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class CustomLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
 private boolean isScrollEnabled = true;

 public CustomLayoutManager (Context context) {
  super(context);
 }

 public void setScrollEnabled(boolean flag) {
  this.isScrollEnabled = flag;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean canScrollVertically() {
  //Similarly you can customize "canScrollHorizontally()" for managing horizontal scroll
  return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollVertically();
 }
}
```

Set this as your recyclerview layout manager and toggle the scrolling with setScrollEnabled(true/false) with the layoutManager object

Assuming your Recyclerview rv

```
 CustomLayoutManager lm=new CustomLayoutManager(context of your activity);
 rv.setLayoutManager(lm);
 lm.setScrollEnabled(true/false);
```

Comment: This does the same as `RecyclerView.stopScroll, it still overshoots when the user flings.

Comment: itemView.rv_child_stories.clearOnScrollListeners() 
            itemView.rv_child_stories.onFlingListener = null  I have achieved it using the  above code sorry it is in kotlin